# jquery Validation on Enter key not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

When I use the submit button on a form validated by the validation form everything run as expected.
 But when I use the Enter key instead of the submit button the validation does not work properly.
Form gets submitted with out checking validation .

How can I solve this problem ?

```
$(function () {
    /* Varable Declarataion..... */
    var $pin = $("#pinCode").attr("name");
    var $params = {debug:false, rules:{}, messages:{}};
    $params['invalidHandler'] = function(form, validator) {
        jQuery(document).scrollLeft(300) ;
        jQuery(document).scrollTop(100);
        var posX = jQuery(document).clientWidth/2;
        var posY = jQuery(document).scrollTop()+(jQuery(document).clientHeight/2);
        $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
            resizable: false,
            height:180,
            modal: true,
            position:[posX,posY],
            buttons: {
               "Ok": function() {
                        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            }
        });
    };
    $params['rules'][$pin] = {required:true, digits :true, maxlength:9, min:1}; 
    $params['messages'][$pin] = {
        required:"Please enter pin code",
        digits :"Please enter a valid pin",
        maxlength:"pin code must be less than 10 digit",
        min: "zero can not be a pin code"
    };
    $("#form1").validate($params);
});
```

Comment: I created a fiddle to try to recreate your problem: http://jsfiddle.net/qgAT4/ The form doesn't gets submitted on clicking submit nor pressing enter when no pincode is given. Can you try to specify your problem in the fiddle?

Comment: thanks for considering my problem . At first we enter name field then press enter then the form will  submitted with out  validating   pin number. it was problem still it persisted in  jsfiddle.net/qgAT4 ..sorry for my english

Comment: It has to do something with the dialog. When the dialog opens the form is submitted, but only when the pinCode field is not focussed. While I have no real explanation for this, I have hacked it to work with a setTimeout with 1 ms: http://jsfiddle.net/qgAT4/2/. I found some resources that one should append the dialogs element to the form element, but that wouldn't help. Maybe someone with more insight can shed some light on this.

Comment: @ohcibi thanks for your valuable suggestion its works fine for me .

Comment: @satheesh you should include the information about the dialog (just use my fiddle) and the concrete steps to reproduce the problem in your question. I tried to edit it, but it got rejected.

Comment: Please add the exact problem description to your OP, along with the rendered HTML of the form, and the browser version you're using.  I am absolutely **not** seeing any form submission in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YTwFY/1/) when the pinCode is left blank, no matter which field is focused.  Also explain exactly what _you think_ this code is supposed to do.

Comment: @Sparky your screenshot shows an empty name field 8-). You have to fill something in to reproduce.

Comment: @ohcibi, I see, the OP really needs to clarify his original question.